# Integrating disparate applications

Tags: web-services, architecture, integration

Systems which require communication between disparate applications is quite commmon.

What is the normal architecture for such applications? Am I right in thinking that web services are the usual tool (if so, what reasons why?).

Also, what other considerations are involved?

Thanks

Comment: You should define more precisely what you mean by application. The communication system depends on their nature. Web services are natural for web apps, not so much for desktop apps. Also, the  environment is very important : Are the applications on the same machine ? What is the underlying OS ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no normal architecture and web services is certainly one way to link them up anda popular one. But the communications technllogy choice is a trivial part of this problem.

Who is communicating what, when and why, is the head scratcher, and of course we can't answer that in anything but the most general of terms.

You need to start with the type of interactions between the applications.

Just retrieving data from another aplication

Requesting another application to perform some function, no feedback of any kind required

Transactional. Do something with this and return a response (synchronous and asynchronous).

Are these applications yours? If so you should head towards SOA. ie you take the processing out of the application, make it a service and then request it. All your other apps then can also request it.

However you go there is no easy solution, because these applications were not designed to work togther.....